# Can I call ReactDOM.render multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a requirement where I need to render the div separately so that I can use that anywhere for that I write like this:-

```
import { render} from 'react-dom';
 render (
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <EmployeeContainerComponent>
                    <DisplayEmployeeComponent
                    />
                </EmployeeContainerComponent>
            </Provider >,
            document.getElementById(headerElementId)
        );
        render(
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <EmployeeContainerComponent>
                    <RameshContainerComponent/>
                </EmployeeContainerComponent>
            </Provider >,
            document.getElementById(elementId)
        );
       render(
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <EmployeeContainerComponent>
                      <SideBaarContainerComponent/>
                </EmployeeContainerComponent>
            </Provider >,
            document.getElementById(sidebarElementId)
        );
```

**Am I doing right ? Is there any performance Issue will come in above approach?**

Comment: What do you mean by `I need to render the div separately so that I can use that anywhere`

Comment: You're sort of using the web components approach. Why not a SPA with multiple components inside ?

Comment: @Fawaz DisplayEmployeeComponent RameshContainerComponent SideBaarContainerComponent  these are component only, but We want all this in some other part of project not in the same div element.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I donot want these component in same div if I will write only one render then all the component will come in one div that why I use three so that In future I can use that any where in project.

Comment: @jack123 Unless you are using some other js frameworks at the same time it makes sense. Otherwise, going with SPA way as I mentioned before you can add as many divs as you need, that's not a limitation. Reusing the components is the basic feature of components based structure so thats a defacto.

Comment: Actually, I face the same problem @Fawaz, it is a business imperative to not go full SPA, so the question and the situation I think is completely valid and deserves a better answer than just: do what I think you should be doing because everybody else is also doing it...